# Send exact Powershell Output in HTML body

Tags: html, powershell, html-email

I have a powershell script that sends an email with some windows events.

$array contains the events

```
$array = (Get-WinEvent -FilterXml ([xml](Get-Content C:\SendMail\EventBackup.xml))| Format-List) | out-string
```

and then in the body of the email, I used to type `$Body=$array` and my report was like:

```
TimeCreated  : 3/16/2015 2:12:52 AM
ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-Backup
Id           : 14
Message      : Backup completed.

TimeCreated  : 3/16/2015 2:12:52 AM
ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-Backup
Id           : 4
Message      : Backup finished successfully.

TimeCreated  : 3/16/2015 1:00:14 AM
ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-Backup
Id           : 1
Message      : Backup started.
```

I have changed the email type to HTML, so I can customize the report, but now the body is like:

```
TimeCreated : 3/19/2015 2:23:00 AM ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-Backup Id : 14 Message : Backup completed. TimeCreated : 3/19/2015 2:23:00 AM ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-Backup Id : 4 Message : Backup finished successfully. TimeCreated : 3/19/2015 1:00:13 AM ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-Backup Id : 1 Message : Backup started.
```

All in the same line.

I know it's maybe because this lines:

```
$emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true
$emailMessage.Body = @"$array "@
```

How can I make it look like before in HTML?

Comment: Try trading that format-list | out-string for ConvertTo-HTML -As List and see if it doesn't look better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to convert new line to `<br/>`

```
$array=$array -replace '\n','<br/>' 
$emailMessage.Body = @"$array "@
```

after you comment : you can use the same technic to put, say the time created, in bold :

```
$array=$array -replace "(Timecreated .*?)(ProviderName)", '<strong>$1</strong>'
```

Comment: Dude, i freaking Love you. 
Thanks  a lot. Did exatly what i needed.
Can i do the same comand to edit TimeCreated to bold or change color?